# search for array inside an array

Tags: javascript

I  need to search for the presence of an array inside an array. It is similar to jQuery.inArray function.

For

```
var a = [ [1,2], [1,3] ];
console.log(  jQuery.inArray([1,3],a  ) )
```

I get -1 as ans. How to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In V8 (that is, Chrome), there is a nifty trick: while `==` does not work for arrays, `<= && >=` does.

You can iterate and check for each item if it's appearent:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] >= [1, 3] && a[i] <= [1, 3]) alert(i);
}
```

For other browsers, you'd need a function that checks for array equality:

http://www.svendtofte.com/code/usefull_prototypes/prototypes.js

```
Array.prototype.compareArrays = function(arr) {
    if (this.length != arr.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].compareArrays) { //likely nested array
            if (!this[i].compareArrays(arr[i])) return false;
            else continue;
        }
        if (this[i] != arr[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i].compareArrays([1, 3])) alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function inArray (needle, haystack) {
   for (var idx in haystack) { 
        if (haystack[idx].join(',') == needle.join(',')) 
          return idx; 
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice but `[[1,2],3].join(",") === [1,[2,3]].join(",")` so it's not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function look4arr(arr, v) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (arr[i].toString() === v.toString()) { //or use +''
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var a = [[1,2], 2],
    ok = [1,2],
    ko = [2,3]
look4arr(a, ok); // true
look4arr(a, ko); // false
// as far as the array you are looking at contains primitives seem to work fine
```

if you need to search for something "more" ...I mean object literals, regexp, functions
You could use a function similar to the following one

```
function look4x(arr, v) {
    for (var i = 0, isObjOrArray = false, l = arr.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        isObjOrArray = {}.toString.call(arr[i]).match(/\[object\s(Array|Object)\]/);
        if (
            (isObjOrArray && JSON.stringify(arr[i])+'' == JSON.stringify(v)+'' )
            ||
            (!isObjOrArray && arr[i].toString() === v.toString())
        ) {
            return true;//or i if a jQuery.inArray output is needed 
        }
    }
    return false; // or -1 ... if ... jQuery.inArray
}
var a = [
        [1,[1,[1,[1,2]]]],
        2,
        true,
        'hei',
        Infinity,
        {"o" : "s", 'd':[1,2,3]},
        new RegExp(/\s/),
        function(){alert('hei');}
    ],
    ok = [1,[1,[1,[1,2]]]];

alert(
    look4x(a, [1,[1,[1,[1,2]]]])
    &&
    look4x(a, true)
    &&
    look4x(a, 'hei')
    &&
    look4x(a, Infinity)
    &&
    look4x(a, {"o" : "s", 'd':[1,2,3]})
    &&
    look4x(a, new RegExp(/\s/))
    &&
    look4x(a, function(){alert('hei');})
); // true, in this case
```

Please note that I didn`t tested it yet with a complete test; I'll post a test asap

Event if I seem to be late, hope it can help someone.

Bye

Comment: ok, now behave correctly searching for array with object literals